# Unable to move scripts under standard_header_includes to footer in HubSpot

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, hubspot

I'm newbie in HubSpot and I need to improve a site's page speed insight score. In this I came across the issue of render blocking elements as all scripts inside the site are loaded in header. I need to move them to the site footer, but seeing no way or option to do so. It seems that all CSS and script files seen in header is included from {{ standard_header_includes }} but I don't see where that code is getting added to move script files to footer. Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You actually control the loading of the scripts where YOU are actually calling them.

So for example anywhere you use `require_js` or `require_css` you actually in that function choose if you want to load in the header, footer, load it async, deferred, etc.

By default module.js is loaded in the footer, module.css is loaded in the header. Each are minified.

The order of your require statements in the actual page determines the ordering of the HTML script and link tags.

I highly recommend checking out the optimizing your CMS Hub site for performance page as it is very thorough on the things you can do to make your site blazingly fast. The JavaScript section in particular is relevant to what you're talking about.
https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/cms/guides/speed#javascript

Also I want to add, If you're inheriting your site from another developer, it's a good idea to look under website settings > pages and see if the developer set domain wide head html. If they did you'll want to review that code and make adjustments to move it to the footer appropriately.

Welcome to the HubSpot developer community @karthika.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I checked in website settings > pages and found it as domain wide code. But in that Site Header HTML, it only includes google tag manager script and a custom script file, nothing else and while the page is rendered it's multiple JS files (like embed_shepherd-v1.js, leadflows.js etc) that's loaded in the header. Seems like its all hub spot loaded script files and not from our side I guess. Couldn't find where this script files are included in the header. I'm inheriting this site from another developer.